# Whether if chlid process's execution reaches the frames inherited from the parent process?

Tags: c++, stack, fork, brute-force, leakcanary

Whenever a process is forked, it inherits the address space of its parent process, i.e., all the in-memory code and data, including the canaries placed in the stack frames and the TLS.Had the stack canary been different for the newly forked processes, attacks that brute-force the canary value byte-bybyte would have been infeasible.However, this partial update will result in an abort if execution reaches the frames inherited from the parent process, as the canary cookies in these frames still hold their old values.consider the example shown in [Fig. 1: Renewing the canary in the TLS alone will result in an abort as soon as execution reaches a stack frame inheritted
from the parent process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzXR1.png)
My question is that is it possible that chlid process's execution reaches the frames inherited from the parent process.

reference: Hawkins, William H., Jason D. Hiser, and Jack W. Davidson. "Dynamic Canary Randomization for Improved Software Security." Proceedings of the 11th Annual Cyber and Information Security Research Conference. ACM, 2016.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. If it weren't possible, why would the authors worry about the effects of it?

Comment: In a forking server(e.g. ngnix), usually use fork+exec or fork+_exit to complete the work, so i doubt that if Fig.1 is only a theoretical situation, In reality there is no non-returnable situation. Child process executes its functions, then exit,  chlid process's execution do not reaches the frames inherited from the parent process.